# How to integrate Google My Business API into a React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, google-my-business-api

I wonder what is the process to integrate Google My Business API into a React app. The main objective is to render the google reviews in the website.

I have been searching in Google documentation but haven't really found any useful guide.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental way is to find the API in the google API store and then render that into the project if there's one. the process includes enabling the API from the store and using REST methods like HTTPS to call them in your project. it's the same for react and all the projects.
[Here's a basic setup link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to apply for Google Business Profile API, for that you need an Account that have verified Google Business Profile. Then you need to implement OAuth2 for authenticating the account that have Google Reviews, once thats done you can access reviews from account that are authenticated. This process may take 2 weeks to 1 month.